# I'm trying to use a stored procedure or function with cursor to cut down on repeated SQL "code", and I'm looking for advice/assistance

Tags: sql-server, function, recursion, cursor

This is kind of a shot in the dark, but I've got a working set of cursors that essentially drill down from a specific parentId (or potentially multiple) through each of its children, its children's children, and that child's children children to essentially reach the bottom of the hierarchy - which will have classification "Base Builds".

Now that I have the actual logic working, I'm looking at this mess as a C# .NET programmer (and not someone particularly skilled in SQL) and find myself wondering whether I can cut down each of these cursors into a single function or stored procedure so it's more easily reused and not so UGLY.

I would like to note that I am aware from my researching cursors that cursors are evil and should be avoided, but my manager is hellbent on me building this in SQL and suggested I use cursor to do so - I will say I'm willing to hear suggestions other than cursors if you happen to know a better way to solve the same problem.

```
DECLARE @parentId varchar(10) = '150192'
DECLARE @compId varchar(10)
DECLARE @classification varchar(50)

DECLARE cursor_one CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT DISTINCT PST.PST_ParentItemID ,PST.PST_CompItemID, IMA.IMA_Classification FROM PST 
    INNER JOIN IMA ON PST.PST_CompItemID = IMA.IMA_ItemID  
    WHERE PST_CompItemID = @parentId --IN ('150192', '150222', '150177', '150176', '150241', '150233', '150203', '150206')
    AND PST_ParentItemID NOT LIKE 'Q%'

OPEN cursor_one
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_one INTO @parentId, @compId, @classification

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Cursor1: ' + @parentId + ' - ' + @compId + ' - ' + @classification
     
    DECLARE cursor_two CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT PST.PST_ParentItemID ,PST.PST_CompItemID, IMA.IMA_Classification FROM PST 
        INNER JOIN IMA ON PST.PST_CompItemID = IMA.IMA_ItemID  
        WHERE PST_CompItemID = @parentId
        AND PST_ParentItemID NOT LIKE 'Q%'

    OPEN cursor_two
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_two INTO @parentId, @compId, @classification

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Cursor2: ' + @parentId + ' - ' + @compId + ' - ' + @classification
----------------------------
        
        DECLARE cursor_three CURSOR FOR
            SELECT DISTINCT PST.PST_ParentItemID ,PST.PST_CompItemID, IMA.IMA_Classification FROM PST 
            INNER JOIN IMA ON PST.PST_CompItemID = IMA.IMA_ItemID  
            WHERE PST_CompItemID = @parentId
            AND PST_ParentItemID NOT LIKE 'Q%'

        OPEN cursor_three
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_three INTO @parentId, @compId, @classification

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Cursor3: ' + @parentId + ' - ' + @compId + ' - ' + @classification
---------------------------

            DECLARE cursor_four CURSOR FOR
                SELECT DISTINCT PST.PST_ParentItemID ,PST.PST_CompItemID, IMA.IMA_Classification FROM PST 
                INNER JOIN IMA ON PST.PST_CompItemID = IMA.IMA_ItemID  
                WHERE PST_CompItemID = @parentId
                AND PST_ParentItemID NOT LIKE 'Q%'

            OPEN cursor_four
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_four INTO @parentId, @compId, @classification

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'Cursor4: ' + @parentId + ' - ' + @compId + ' - ' + @classification
---------------------------

                DECLARE cursor_five CURSOR FOR
                    SELECT DISTINCT PST.PST_ParentItemID ,PST.PST_CompItemID, IMA.IMA_Classification FROM PST 
                    INNER JOIN IMA ON PST.PST_CompItemID = IMA.IMA_ItemID  
                    WHERE PST_CompItemID = @parentId
                    AND PST_ParentItemID NOT LIKE 'Q%'

                OPEN cursor_five
                FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_five INTO @parentId, @compId, @classification

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN
                    PRINT 'Cursor5: ' + @parentId + ' - ' + @compId + ' - ' + @classification
----------------------------

                    DECLARE cursor_six CURSOR FOR
                        SELECT DISTINCT PST.PST_ParentItemID ,PST.PST_CompItemID, IMA.IMA_Classification FROM PST 
                        INNER JOIN IMA ON PST.PST_CompItemID = IMA.IMA_ItemID  
                        WHERE PST_CompItemID = @parentId
                        AND PST_ParentItemID NOT LIKE 'Q%'

                    OPEN cursor_six
                    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_six INTO @parentId, @compId, @classification

                    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                    BEGIN
                        PRINT 'Cursor6: ' + @parentId + ' - ' + @compId + ' - ' + @classification
                        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_six INTO @parentId, @compId, @classification
                    END
                    CLOSE cursor_six
                    DEALLOCATE cursor_six

----------------------------
                    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_five INTO @parentId, @compId, @classification
                END
                CLOSE cursor_five
                DEALLOCATE cursor_five

----------------------------
                FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_three INTO @parentId, @compId, @classification
            END
            CLOSE cursor_four
            DEALLOCATE cursor_four

---------------------------
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_three INTO @parentId, @compId, @classification
        END
        CLOSE cursor_three
        DEALLOCATE cursor_three

----------------------------
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_two INTO @parentId, @compId, @classification
    END
    CLOSE cursor_two
    DEALLOCATE cursor_two

    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_one INTO @parentId, @compId, @classification
    END
END
CLOSE cursor_one
DEALLOCATE cursor_one
```

And an output like so is returned for testing's sake:

```
Cursor1: 150193 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor2: 10971 - 150193 - Packaging
Cursor3: 200871 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 220011 - 200871 - Base Builds
Cursor4: 200872 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 200873 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 200874 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 200875 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 200876 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 200880 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 200881 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 200909 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 200910 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 200941 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 200942 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 200954 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 200964 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor5: 220026 - 200964 - Base Builds
Cursor4: 200965 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 200985 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 200986 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 201085 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 201086 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 201222 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 201232 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 201243 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor5: 220050 - 201243 - Base Builds
Cursor4: 201314 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 201359 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 340088 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 340089 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 340090 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 340093 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 340095 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 340100 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 340103 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 340107 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 340132 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 340135 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 340152 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 340173 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 340179 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor4: 340237 - 10971 - Fabricated Items
Cursor2: 10979 - 150193 - Packaging
Cursor3: 200877 - 10979 - Fabricated Items
Cursor3: 200878 - 10979 - Fabricated Items
Cursor3: 200919 - 10979 - Fabricated Items
Cursor3: 200920 - 10979 - Fabricated Items
Cursor1: 240044 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 240063 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 240071 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 240085 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 240108 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 240118 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 240120 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 240158 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 240176 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 240224 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 240283 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 240436 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 240470 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 240504 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 240522 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 250008 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 250009 - 150192 - Packaging
Cursor1: 250010 - 150192 - Packaging
```

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: For SQL Server look at using a recursive common table expression (CTE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a recursive CTE (Common Table Expression), something similar to the following...

```sql
declare @ParentID varchar(10) = '150192';

with Hierarchy as (
  -- "Root" node(s)
  select distinct 1 as Level, PST.PST_ParentItemID as ParentID, PST.PST_CompItemID as CompID, IMA.IMA_Classification as Classification
  from PST
  inner join IMA on PST.PST_CompItemID = IMA.IMA_ItemID
  where PST_CompItemID = @ParentId
  and PST_ParentItemID not like 'Q%'

  union all

  -- "Child" node(s)
  select 1+Level, PST.PST_ParentItemID, PST.PST_CompItemID, IMA.IMA_Classification
  from Hierarchy
  inner join PST on PST_CompItemID = ParentID and PST_ParentItemID not like 'Q%'
  inner join IMA on PST.PST_CompItemID = IMA.IMA_ItemID
)
select Level, ParentID, CompID, Classification
from Hierarchy
```

Which returns output similar to the following...

| Level | ParentID | CompID | Classification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 150193 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240044 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240063 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240071 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240085 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240108 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240118 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240120 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240158 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240176 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240224 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240283 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240436 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240470 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240504 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 240522 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 250008 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 250009 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 1 | 250010 | 150192 | Packaging |
| 2 | 10971 | 150193 | Packaging |
| 2 | 10979 | 150193 | Packaging |
| 3 | 200877 | 10979 | Fabricated Items |
| 3 | 200878 | 10979 | Fabricated Items |
| 3 | 200919 | 10979 | Fabricated Items |
| 3 | 200920 | 10979 | Fabricated Items |
| 3 | 200871 | 10971 | Fabricated Items |

...

Comment: I finally got to actually implementing this today - this is fantastic and you're a lifesaver thank you so much!